# Wordpress not sending e-mails from AWS

Tags: wordpress, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, wordpress-theming

the issue I am having is that the installed Wordpress theme is not sending e-mails, for example between various user profiles, notification e-mails etc.

I have installed Wordpress on AWS and I used AWS Marketplace to download and install Bitnami image "WordPress Certified by Bitnami and Automattic".

The theme owner looked at the site and the response I received is that everything is fine with the theme. According to her the problem is on AWS side.

In this context, I'd like to ask talented AWS experts for a little help with getting the e-mails rolling from my Wordpress site/theme.

Thank you!

Comment: You have to request they open SMTP ports. https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/smtp-connectivity-timeout-issues-ses/

Comment: @HowardE: Thanks for the link. I could not get much far with it unfortunately, because I am no a cloud expert. Described Telnet command on my cmd results in black screen (does that mean the connection was successful). For the next step - I could not find where to run openssl command. Do you mind helping me with this please? Thanks!

Comment: https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/ec2-port-25-throttle/